# Liferay Association Listener Functionalitiy

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want know the purpose and the functionality of association related listeners in liferay BaseModelListener.

Ex : `onBeforeAddAssociation` , `onAfterRemoveAssociation` , `onAfterAddAssociation`

Any ideas are really appreciated, because no proper documentation was found.

Comment: Is there any particular problem you're looking forward to solve with this or just plain academic interest?

Comment: Actually I'm creating a listener for JounalArticle model. I was able to create listener and its working properly. I was wandering that, we can use association listeners for listen to JournalArticle associated/related classes. (Ex: Layout). If so, we will not need to implement a another listener.

Comment: Typically ModelListeners are good for anything persistence-related and service-wrappers are good for business-layer overrides. In 95% of times, it's better to override on the business layer instead of the model layer - you might want to check this instead. (I don't know of more exact documentation for those, you'd probably have to read the source - make sure you have a persistence issue though, not a business issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the question in liferay [forum](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/41906601) and got the answer. According to **David H Nebinger** these listeners will not be invoked ever.

> They were intended to be used when (if) collections were supported in
>   the model objects. Since they are not supported They will not be
>   invoked.